# incomplete Git clone

Tags: git, github

I am working on a web project and we're using Git vcs.  I am using the ubuntu distribution of linux. Please why isn't "clone" copying all the files in the repo to my local dev directory from the github? I've tried cloning several times, it does clone the repo but the files are incomplete(hidden files are missing)

Comment: Welcome to stack **overflow**. If you expand on your question and describe the problem you're having more completely, you'll more likely get a solution.

Comment: we have a repo on github. I try cloning the repo from github from ubuntu's terminal using '$git clone https://github.com/fatihalp/fefweb.git /var/www/fefweb'. It clones the repo to the fefweb directory. However, it does not clone some essential files. so it's incomplete.

Comment: Are these files listed within the .gitignore file for the repo?

Comment: not they aren't . the .gitignore file is separate. here are the files not being cloned or at least not visible to in my dev directory: .gitignore, .editorconfig, .travis.yml and .htaccess

Comment: Are you sure you are listing hidden files? All files starting with a '.' are hidden. Try `ls -la`

Comment: hmm they are actually there. I completely forgot about that command. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that those files ( `.gitignore`, `.editorconfig`, `.travis.yml` and `.htaccess`) are not hidden (there is no hidden attribute in Unix like you have in Windows)
And git wouldn't store that metadata information anyway.

They simple aren't directly listed by a simple ls.

So `git clone` *does* clone everything.

But to see *all* the files, including the dotfiles, you need a `ls -a` (as [Steinar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1969893/steinar) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236130/incomplete-git-clone#comment21482926_15236130)).

You can define an alias like:

```
 alias lh='ls -a | egrep "^\."'
```

And '`lh`' would display *only* the dotfiles.